# changing color on primary & primaryDark

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am using a Toolbar & I want to change the color of primary & primaryDark.
I follow this tutorial and the guy in the video use this code:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hqfSuyuRhmU

```
<item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
```

I have two styles.xml, one for L-version & one for the rest.
When I use that code in the styles for the rest, I will get 2 errors.

1. that the code requires api21, im using api14, minimum (4.0)
2. cannot resolve @color/primary.

The first I can understand, because this styles.xml are for everything but but api21.
so what do I need to use for anything under api21?

The second error, I think the problem is that I dont have primary/primaryDark. I do have primary material dark and so on, so the tutorial is old?

And the most important.
When I use primary material dark, i will get black as color.
If i want to change my primary and primary dark, how should I do it?
The guy in the video gets yellow color, I get black, but want to change.

Can I create a primary/primaryDark and give it a specific color?

**EDIT:**

first pic. my appcompat dependencies.
second pic. my regular styles.xml with 2 errors.
third pic. my styles.xml for v21 Lollipop, one error.

[image: the dependencies in my gradle.]

[image: my styles.xml, look at the errors.]

[image: my styles.xml for v21. Have one les error, but still, cant find primary/primaryDark]

Answer (score -2):

Just create a colors.XML and define your colors there 
Ex: 
#f44336